# Comparing the definition for the pullback of generic vector bundles and the one for differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, vector-bundles

Here is the definition for a pullback induced by a function $f: N \rightarrow M$ on a generic vector bundle $\pi: E \rightarrow M$:

$$f^∗(E) = \{ (p,e) \in M×E \ | \ f(p) = \pi (e) \}$$

For instance, this means that the fibers of the pullback of the bundle of alternating forms $(f^* (\Lambda M))_p$ can be identified with $\Lambda _{f(p)} M = \text{Alt} (T^* _{f(p)} M)$.

The pullback of a differential form is then naturally defined as

$$f^* \omega : p \mapsto (p, \omega \circ f) = (p, f(p), \omega_{f(p)})$$

where $ \omega_{f(p)} \in \text{Alt}(T ^* _{f(p)} M ) $ so that $f^* \omega$ is a section of $f^∗ (\Lambda M)$.

But then I've came across a definition specific for differential forms:

$$f^*\omega : p \mapsto (p, \omega_{f(p)} \circ d_p f)$$

Where the composition is intended for each input vector. This clearly is no longer a section of $f^∗(\Lambda M)$ but a section of $\Lambda N$, as $ \omega_{f(p)} \circ d_p f \in \text{Alt}(T ^* _{p} N ) $, so these two are not consistent.

Comment: That’s because pullback of differential forms is dual to push-forward of   tangent spaces. Pullback of bundles has nothing to do with the differentiable structure; it is completely topological.

Comment: So you're saying that these two definitions are indeed incompatible. Should I understand which one is being used by context, or is the first one just never adopted for differential forms?

Comment: The first one almost never appears.

Comment: Note that we pull back differential forms (sections), not the bundles. On the other hand, we push forward tangent spaces (i.e., the tangent bundle) but in general cannot push forward vector fields (sections).

Comment: Given a vector bundle $E$ on $M$ and a map $f: M \rightarrow N$, then any section $s$of $E$ can be pulled back to a section $f^*s = s\circ f$ of $f^*E$.

At each $p \in N$, the pushforward of $f$ defines a linear map $f_*: T_pN \rightarrow T_{f(p)}M$. Its dual map is the pullback map $f^*: T_{f(p)}^*M \rightarrow T_p^*N$. This in turn induces a natural map $f^*: \Lambda^k_{f(p)}M \rightarrow \Lambda^k_pN$. You could, if you want, view the pullback of a differential form as the composition of the two pullback maps, but it's not necessary to do this.